# How can convert a list of strings contain html tag in vue3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am using data of an array that contains string included html tags. The defined loop is as follows:

```
<template>
 <v-expansion-panel-text v-for="(subField, index) in  subFields.failed_audits" :key="index">
                        <div class="d-flex pa-4 align-end justify-center flex-column w-100">
                          <v-alert class="d-flex align-end justify-start ltr-dir w-100" type="error" variant="outlined"
                            :title="subField.title">
                            <v-alert-description>
                              <p class='d-flex' v-html="subField.description"></p>
                            </v-alert-description>
                          </v-alert>

                        </div>
      </v-expansion-panel-text>
</template>
```

Actually, the variable of `subField.description` includes html tags such as `<a>`.
When i defined v-html, the following error appears and no content is displayed:
`:v-html will override element children`.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The element that has the directive `v-html` must not include any attributes or classes.